# How to store json to database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to Android Application Development. Please help me how to store JSON file to my sqlite3 database.

Thanks for helping...

Comment: [Store json to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563118/how-to-save-data-from-json-in-sqlite-in-android/6563180#6563180)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309075/what-is-the-best-way-to-deal-with-json-object

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525298/store-json-in-an-sqlite-field

Answer (score 1):

u have json content. First u have to split all the datas from that.(It is in the form of json object and json array).
U ll get as string, 
 then put into database.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `JSON object` as a `String` form .. What problem are you getting in that?

Answer (score 0):

You need parse the jsonobject to stings ,For json parsing you can go through with following link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/